# UserDefaults Not Saving and Incrementing Properly

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using UserDefaults to save values to determine when to present an interstitial ad within my application.

Here is the code used to increment the numbers:

```
if((defaults.integer(forKey: PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER) > defaults.integer(forKey: CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER))){

        print("1111")

        let oldNumber = defaults.integer(forKey: CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER)
        let newNumber = oldNumber + 1
        defaults.set(newNumber, forKey: CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER)

        print("oldNumber \(oldNumber)")
        print("newNumber \(newNumber)")
        print("INTER NUMBER \(defaults.integer(forKey: CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER))")
        print(defaults.integer(forKey: PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER))
    }
```

I declare user defaults as follows `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard`

My problem is that is it doesn't always increment the values correctly. I have toyed with this for about an hour to try and work it out.

CASE 1:

```
CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 0
PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 4
```

... run incrementing code ...

```
CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 1
PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 4
```

... run incrementing code ...

```
CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 1
PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 4
```

... run incrementing code ...

```
CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 1
PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 4
```

... run incrementing code ...

```
CURRENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 2
PRESENT_INTERSTITIAL_NUMBER = 4
```

It appears to be random when the value doesn't properly carry over, but I can't figure out why it is doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you killing the app in between run of the incrementing code?

Comment: @AshleyMills Thank you! I tested without my device plugged in and it seemed that maybe that was the issue!